# Predicting match outcomes based on moving averages

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, first of all, not really a question about code, but I don't know which stack to ask in

I decided to make a sports gambling script so I could quit my job and never work again.
I just started and I read about Poisson distributions (which kind of approximate the chance of X goals getting scored). Then I found out about Skellam distributions, which are sort of like an overlay of 2 Poisson Distributions, and determine the probability that X events in one Poisson distribution will occur Y more times than a similar X event in another Poisson distribution (ie. probability that Home team will score Y more goals than Away team).

Poisson distribution only needs an average value to be calculated, likewise Skellam only needs 2 average values.

So I scraped data from hockey game and passed in averages of the last *n* games, (exponential and simple moving averages) for the home and away team. Sometimes calculating moving average just for last *n* home games for home team, and last *n* away games for away team.

This isn't super sophisticated, and when I pass in these averages to [the skellam function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skellam.html), the 'mean' returned is just the difference between the two means. (I should probably learn more about this function, but for now, that is ok, intuitively would expect it to be around that).

Ok, so here is my question. I pass in an upcoming game, calculate the Skellam mean based on recent moving averages of the goals scored by home and away teams, which ends up being, as I mentioned, just this difference.

Then I look through all the games in my dataset (last 4 years or so) and look for games where the Skellam mean was very close to this (based on moving averages of goals scored leading up to said games).
Then I look to see what percentage of those games ended up having actual scores that corresponded.

I am finding that if you picked the team that was predicted to score more goals based on moving averages, you would be correct most of the time. The higher the difference, the more likely you are to guess right, as expected.

Ok, you say, that is why bookies have lines. Even when I factor in the lines, for many games, I would win a lot of money making bets based on these moving averages (ema a little better than sma).

**This seems too good to be true, anybody know if I am missing something. Or are bookies making money just because so many people pick the wrong team (like, if the home-away moving average is negative, they pick the hometeam)?**

For what it is worth, here are just a few scenarios my code spit out

```
======================================
Home: COL (2.5 ALL_gf_sma_6), Away: TBL (3.1666666666666665 ALL_gf_sma_6), 

For Game None (2020-02-17)

Skellam Spread: -0.6666666666666665

                for mean of interest -0.6666666666666665

                74 correct out of 130, 0.5692307692307692


                line is -125, so ACCORDING TO THIS model, if I make 100 1$ bets
                on TBL at -125
                I should win 2.46153846153846



======================================
Home: COL (2.408749692130294 ALL_gf_ema_6), Away: TBL (3.46238588221631 ALL_gf_ema_6), 

For Game None (2020-02-17)

Skellam Spread: -1.0536361900860158

                for mean of interest -1.0536361900860158

                95 correct out of 112, 0.8482142857142857


                line is -125, so ACCORDING TO THIS model, if I make 100 1$ bets
                on TBL at -125
                I should win 52.67857142857143



======================================
Home: COL (3.0 ALL_gf_sma_7), Away: TBL (3.2857142857142856 ALL_gf_sma_7), 

For Game None (2020-02-17)

Skellam Spread: -0.2857142857142856

                for mean of interest -0.2857142857142856

                72 correct out of 152, 0.47368421052631576


                line is -125, so ACCORDING TO THIS model, if I make 100 1$ bets
                on TBL at -125
                I should win -14.736842105263172



======================================
Home: COL (2.5499815075403176 ALL_gf_ema_7), Away: TBL (3.4296477035135826 ALL_gf_ema_7), 

For Game None (2020-02-17)

Skellam Spread: -0.879666195973265

                for mean of interest -0.879666195973265

                99 correct out of 121, 0.8181818181818182


                line is -125, so ACCORDING TO THIS model, if I make 100 1$ bets
                on TBL at -125
                I should win 47.272727272727295
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question is both too broad and highly opinion-based, and both are reasons to close it on stack overflow. You might try [stats.se] for a statistical view, or possibly [money.se] for a personal finance/money oriented view, although that might be a stretch of that stack's rules

Comment: This question, while interesting, is not appropriate for CV. However bookies make money due to the spread. People "pick" the wrong team because it pays out more to bet on the underdog than the expected winner. Without spreads, bookies wouldn't be making any money since everyone would just bet on the expected winner. For example a spread with a 100 bet could pay out 107 for the expected winner, or 300 for the underdog. Potentially making 200 more dollars would be better than definitely making 7 for most people. So its worthwhile to not always go with the expected winner.

Comment: Food for thought.